# Colocar datos en cada INPUT de una tabla

Tags: javascript

Buen día.
Estimados solicito de su ayuda con el siguiente caso:
Estoy obteniendo tanto el equipo y el puntaje en un solo INPUT, pero lo ideal es que cada dato obtenido se pase a cada INPUT correspondiente para no mezclar la información. Adjunto script.

```js
function calcular(){       
                // declaracion de variables
                var pts = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='PTS']");         
                var equipo = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='Equipo']");
                
                var arreglo= [];
                // crear array objeto con finalista
               
                for (var i = 0; i < pts.length;i++) {
                      
                    arreglo.push({"equipo":equipo[i].innerHTML,"pts":pts[i].innerHTML});
                   console.log(arreglo);
                }
             
           
                // funcion para ordenar objeto array
                 arreglo.sort(function (a,b) {
                    if (a.pts < b.pts) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                 
                  if (a.pts > b.pts) {
                     return -1;
                    }
                    // a must be equal to b
                    return 0;
                });
            var maxPuntuacion = 30; 
    for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        arreglo[i].pts = maxPuntuacion; 
        maxPuntuacion -= 10;
     document.getElementById(arreglo[i].equipo).value = 'Equipo: ' + arreglo[i].equipo + ' - puntos: ' + arreglo[i].pts;
    }
    
                    // Salida / construccion de contenido
                    contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts;
                    contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[1].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[1].pts;
                    contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[2].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[2].pts;
                     
                     alert(contenido);   
       }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
         <label>EQUIPO1</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipor" id="ROJO">
          <label>puntaje</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipor" id="pr" size="2">
          <label>EQUIPO2</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipoa" id="AMARILLO">
          <label>Puntaj3</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipoa" id="pa" size="2">
          <label>EQUIPO4</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipot" id="TURQUESA">
          <label>puntaje</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipot" id="pt" size="2">
      </form>
    <table id="datos">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Genero</th>
                <th>Equipo</th>
                <th>PJ</th>
                <th>PG</th>
                <th>PP</th>
                <th>PE</th>
                <th>GF</th>
                <th>GC</th>
                <th>DFG</th>
                <th>PTS</th>
                <th>Calcular Ganador</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">ROJO</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">1</td>
                <td data-title="PP">1</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">3</td>
                <td data-title="GC">4</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">-1</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">3</td>
                <td rowspan="3"><input type="button" value="Pasar" class="pasar" onclick="calcular()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">AMARILLO</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">2</td>
                <td data-title="PP">0</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">7</td>
                <td data-title="GC">1</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">6</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">TURQUESA</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">0</td>
                <td data-title="PP">2</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">1</td>
                <td data-title="GC">6</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">-5</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">0</td>
            </tr>
           
            <div id="contenido">
            
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

esto deberia quedar asi:

```
Equipo1 en su respectivo input rojo y en otro input el puntaje.
Equipo2 en su respectivo amarillo y en otro input el puntaje.
Equipo3 en su respectivo turqueza y en otro input el puntaje.
```

Claro esto se realiza desde la funcion del javascript
Espero su apoyo con este tema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El funcionamiento es el mismo a seguir, si quieres insertar datos en un `input` en concreto, basta con asignarle un `id`, acceder a ese elemento y modificar su valor.

Estos son los dos cambios en el código `JavaScript` en base a lo que he comentado antes.

```
document.getElementById(arreglo[i].equipo).value = arreglo[i].equipo;
document.getElementById(arreglo[i].equipo + '-PTS').value = arreglo[i].pts;
```

En el código `HTML` tan solo he modificado el `id` de los `inputs` de puntaje.

```js
function calcular(){       
                // declaracion de variables
                var pts = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='PTS']");         
                var equipo = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='Equipo']");
                
                var arreglo= [];
                // crear array objeto con finalista
               
                for (var i = 0; i < pts.length;i++) {
                      
                    arreglo.push({"equipo":equipo[i].innerHTML,"pts":pts[i].innerHTML});
                   console.log(arreglo);
                }
             
           
                // funcion para ordenar objeto array
                 arreglo.sort(function (a,b) {
                    if (a.pts < b.pts) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                 
                  if (a.pts > b.pts) {
                     return -1;
                    }
                    // a must be equal to b
                    return 0;
                });
            var maxPuntuacion = 30; 
    for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        arreglo[i].pts = maxPuntuacion; 
        maxPuntuacion -= 10;
     document.getElementById(arreglo[i].equipo).value = arreglo[i].equipo;
     document.getElementById(arreglo[i].equipo + '-PTS').value = arreglo[i].pts;
    }
    
                    // Salida / construccion de contenido
                    contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts;
                    contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[1].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[1].pts;
                    contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[2].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[2].pts;
 
       }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
         <label>EQUIPO1</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipor" id="ROJO">
          <label>puntaje</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipor" id="ROJO-PTS" size="2">
          <label>EQUIPO2</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipoa" id="AMARILLO">
          <label>Puntaje</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipoa" id="AMARILLO-PTS" size="2">
          <label>EQUIPO4</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipot" id="TURQUESA">
          <label>puntaje</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipot" id="TURQUESA-PTS" size="2">
      </form>
    <table id="datos">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Genero</th>
                <th>Equipo</th>
                <th>PJ</th>
                <th>PG</th>
                <th>PP</th>
                <th>PE</th>
                <th>GF</th>
                <th>GC</th>
                <th>DFG</th>
                <th>PTS</th>
                <th>Calcular Ganador</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">ROJO</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">1</td>
                <td data-title="PP">1</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">3</td>
                <td data-title="GC">4</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">-1</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">3</td>
                <td rowspan="3"><input type="button" value="Pasar" class="pasar" onclick="calcular()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">AMARILLO</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">2</td>
                <td data-title="PP">0</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">7</td>
                <td data-title="GC">1</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">6</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">TURQUESA</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">0</td>
                <td data-title="PP">2</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">1</td>
                <td data-title="GC">6</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">-5</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">0</td>
            </tr>
           
            <div id="contenido">
            
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```